# iOS and Android [type=number] setSelectionRange vs. select

Tags: javascript, input, selection

I am attempting to highlight the text of an `input[type=number]` by clicking it. I originally tried `select()` which worked for Chrome (Android), but it did not work for Safari (iOS).

So I found a piece of code which recommended I try `setSelectionRange(0, nativeEl.value.length);`

This worked well for iOS! However, for Chrome, it crashes:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setSelectionRange' on 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number') does not support selection.
```

So one method works for one platform, not the other, and vice versa.

My question is, what is the best way to determine the best platform differences without browser sniffing? `setSelectionRange` is present on both Chrome and Safari instances of `input`. Thus, checking for that property is redundant.

The best code I have come up with so far is as follows:

```
let nativeEl: HTMLInputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('input');

if (nativeEl) {
  if (nativeEl.setSelectionRange) {
    // select the text from start to end
    try {
      nativeEl.setSelectionRange(0, nativeEl.value.length);
    } catch (e) {
      nativeEl.select();
    }
  }

  nativeEl.select();
}
```

But it seems an antipattern to rely on a catch statement. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What happens after a successfull nativeEl.setSelectionRange(0, nativeEl.value.length);? You are calling nativeEl.select(); after the if (nativeEl.setSelectionRange) { ... }  Would it not be better to have a else { nativeEl.select(); }?

Comment: @D.Braun - unfortunately Chrome has the property `setSelectionRange` which causes the crash on Chrome (not on Safari).

Comment: I mean:

if (nativeEl) {
  if (nativeEl.setSelectionRange) {
    // select the text from start to end
    try {
      nativeEl.setSelectionRange(0, nativeEl.value.length);
    } catch (e) {
      nativeEl.select();
    }
  }
  else {
    nativeEl.select(); 
  }
}

Comment: I know that is not the answer. It is only a comment. :-)

Comment: Got you :) yeah I think that will be the implementation. I was trying to avoid relying on a catch, but I believe it's the only way in this instance?

Comment: This could help: http://wisercoder.com/input-select-does-not-work-on-ios/

Comment: Awesome find - thanks :)

Comment: `setSelectionRange` Doesn't seem to be working on safari anymore